# What's the file system layout on an Azure VM?

Tags: linux, mount, azure

I just created a virtual machine with Azure. According to the settings I used, it should have 32 GiB of temp storage plus a 30 GiB disk.

To get an overview, I ran `df` on the machine. This is the output:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev             8180760       0   8180760   0% /dev
tmpfs            1639832     684   1639148   1% /run
/dev/sdb1       30309264 1372304  28920576   5% /
tmpfs            8199152       0   8199152   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120       0      5120   0% /run/lock
tmpfs            8199152       0   8199152   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sdb15        106858    3686    103173   4% /boot/efi
/dev/sda1       32894736   49180  31151556   1% /mnt
tmpfs            1639828       0   1639828   0% /run/user/1000
```

If I understand this correctly,

- the 30 GiB disk is mounted to `/`, meaning that most directories by default are on the main disk;
- the 32 GiB temp storage is mounted to `/mnt`.

It seems to me that `/tmp` is a regular subdirectory of `/`, which would mean that any files placed in `/tmp` would end up on the main disk rather than in temp storage.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: In the current state of affairs anything written to `/tmp` would indeed ne on the root fs.

But: You can decide what gets mounted where - just edit `/etc/fstab` or manually remount to your liking. In addition to that, nothing stops you from doing `bind` mounts to your liking as well or even create image files on your tempdisk and `loop`-mount the wherever you want

The latter trades a small overhead versus the fact, that you can just copy, move, upload or download the image file after unmounting it. This can come in handy with cloud VMs.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation! I just wanted to make sure that my understanding of the initial configuration was correct, but your tips are welcome, too!